What's this 90s movie about christmas (scene) and poisoning (scene)?
I only have two memories left of this movie.
I watched it on (German) TV as a kid (in the 90s). I guess it is an American 90s movie. And I think the genre must be comedy/tragedy/road movie.
Scene A
There is a longer scene where people are at a familiy home. I have the feeling the protagonist got invited to the house or was begging for a stay.
There is a christmas tree and the people are having a good time. 
Then there's some kind of a twist, where the people in the house are being poisoned unknowingly. They take it in form of food or a drink. I can clearly remember a woman (red to brown hair, about 20 to 30 years old) who consumed the poison. When the poison takes effect, her mouth fills up with blood (and it spills out of her mouth). This is a surprising and shocking scene (for the attendees of the meeting as well).
The protagonist is not the poisoner.
Scene B
Then I remember there is another scene in a car workshop or some other kind of factory building. It might be before that poison scene or after it or it might even be shown several times throughout the movie. The protagonist is also shown there.
It is possible that the first described scene was just taking place at christmas and the rest of the movie is not about christmas.
What makes me still remember this movie is the peaceful christmas scene which gets distorted by that horrible poison death.

Care to explain the down vote? I tried to gather all of my memories about this flick. It's hard to come up with a better question, if you just don't remember the details anymore.

Don't worry about a few ID haters and their downvotes.  This is a great ID question with plenty of information! +1 :)

150 is too much bro. You should keep in mind while offering a bounty. You have lost a basic privilege of commenting on other's posts.

@SS thanks for the advice. I didn't know that. I still have 51 though, haven't I? :)

Just to make sure, this isn't The last supper, is it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(1996_film)

@GustavoGabriel No, I would have remembered that plot line. But thanks for the suggestion. The movie was not mainly about murdering.

@GustavoGabriel - awesome movie.  I highly recommend it for Torsten.
